# How to execute Dynamically created query in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016, sql-server-2016-express

I have written a stored procedure Where I have written a query to get `userid`. There is a separate database for every `userid`. So I am trying to run a select query based on this userid obtained from my previous select query in a loop.

And I am trying to assign the columns in this select query to variables declared and use them further. But I am not understanding how to assign these to variables as I am getting errors

```
    USE DATABASE1
    GO
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE [User].[update_client_details] 
    AS
    DECLARE
    @clientdata CURSOR,
    @clientid INT,
    @SQL VARCHAR(2000),
    @uid INT
    @isactive INT,
    @createdDate Date

    BEGIN
        SET @clientdata = CURSOR FOR
        SELECT clientuserid FROM User.queen_client


        OPEN @clientdata
        FETCH NEXT
        FROM @clientdata INTO @clientid
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SET @SQL = N'SELECT @uid=userid, @isactive=isactive, @createdDate=createddate FROM ['+CAST(@clientid AS NVARCHAR(20))+'].User.queen_user';
            EXEC (@SQL)
            IF(@isactive = 1)
            BEGIN
            //do someting//
            END
        END

        CLOSE @clientdata
        DEALLOCATE @clientdata

    END
```

if the execute the store procedure it is getting executed and not stopping. If I force stop the execution then I am getting the error as "must declare the scalar variable "`uid`""

### Query Which I tried

```
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @uid=userid, @isactive=isactive, @createdDate=createddate FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@clientid)+'.QueenBase.queen_user', N'@clienid int, @uid int OUTPUT, @createDate date OUTPUT';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables only persist and exist within the scope that they are declared in. Therefore both the following batches will fail:

```
DECLARE @I int = 1;
EXEC (N'SELECT @i;');

GO

EXEC (N'DECLARE @I int = 1;');
SELECT @i;
```

When using dynamic SQL, don't use `EXEC(@SQL);`, use `sp_executesql`. Then you can parametrise the statement. For example:

```
DECLARE @I int = 1;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @i;', N'@i int', @i;
```

This returns `1`. If you need to return a value to the outer SQL, as a parameter, you need to use `OUTPUT` parameters:

```
DECLARE @I int = 10;
DECLARE @O int;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'SELECT @O = @I / 2;', N'@I int, @O int OUTPUT', @I, @O OUTPUT;

SELECT @O;
```

This assigns the value `5` to the variable `@O` (which is then selected).

Also, don't use `N'...[' + @SomeVariable + N'] ...'` to inject dynamic values, it's not injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME`: `N'...' + QUOTENAME(@SomeVariable) + N'...'`

*Additional note. The fact that you need to do something like `N'FROM ['+CAST(@clientid AS NVARCHAR(20))+'].User.queen_user'` suggests a severe design flaw, but that's a different topic.*

If you do fancy additional reading, I cover a lot of considerations you need to take into account in my article [Dos and Don'ts of Dynamic SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dos-and-donts-of-dynamic-sql).

---

For your attempt, it's not working as you use an expression for the first parameter (not a literal or variable) and then don't pass any of the parameters you define:

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT @uid=userid, @isactive=isactive, @createdDate=createddate FROM ' +QUOTENAME(@clientid)+'.QueenBase.queen_user;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@isactive int OUTPUT, @uid int OUTPUT, @createDate date OUTPUT', @isactive OUTPUT, @uid OUTPUT, @createDate OUTPUT;
```

Comment: Can you please help me in rewriting the query in the format which you are explained  SELECT @uid=userid, @isactive=isactive, @createdDate=createddate FROM ['+CAST(@clientid AS NVARCHAR(20))+'].User.queen_user

Comment: What failed when you tried, @Saisri , or what part did you not understand and I can try to elaborate more,

Comment: I have tried the query which I posted in the question above

Comment: Yes, and I explained in the above @Saisri , don't use `EXEC (@SQL)` as you can't parametrise it. Use `sys.sp_executesql`, like I demonstrate above.

Comment: I have edited the question and I have added the query tried under the heading "Query Which I tried"

Comment: The first parameter needs to be a literal or variable, not an expression, @Saisri . YOu then need to actually pass the parameters to that SP.

Comment: Can you please correct my query and type it down. So that I can understand better

Comment: Added an **untested** version, @Saisri .

Comment: a small help. How do I loop parameter SQL query output?

Comment: If you're wanting to loop you have another problem, @Saisri . Looping in SQL Server always been you have a major design flaw. Use Set-based solutions.

Comment: I am new to sql. I think its beyond my knowledge to understand what your saying. Can you help me out in this?

Comment: You're asking a new question there, @Saisri , so you should be posting a new question. But, like I said, you should not be looping in SQL, it's a set-based language not a programmatical one.

Comment: So what do I need to do because the output of SQL parameter query here is not a single row. and I need to verify each row output using an IF statement

Comment: ... *"You're asking a new question there, @Saisri , so you should be [posting a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)."*

Comment: Ok I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62284453/how-to-loop-a-query-that-is-created-dynamically-in-sql-server

Comment: Are u looking into the new question?